# Almacenar dentro de un arreglo valores para luego mostrarlo a la vista React JS

Tags: javascript, nodejs, firebase, reactjs

Estoy haciendo una aplicación donde necesito guardar en un arreglo unos productos, este arreglo logra almacenar los productos traidos de la base de datos, pero el detalle es que cuando lo voy a mostrar a la vista, no me aparece nada, como si estuviera vacio, ¿qué estoy haciendo mal? Gracias por su ayuda.

```
class Home extends Component{

constructor(){
    super();
    this.products = [];
    this.obtenerProductos = this.obtenerProductos.bind(this);
}

obtenerProductos(){
    const referencia = firebase.database().ref().child('products').orderByKey();
    referencia.once('value', snap => {
    snap.forEach(child => {

        var productElement = {
            id:          child.key, 
            name:        child.val().name, 
            price:       child.val().price,
            image:       child.val().image,
            category:    child.val().category,
            description: child.val().description
        };

        this.products.push(productElement);
       });
    });
}
```

En la función render(), tengo lo siguiente:

```
render(){ 
  this.obtenerProductos(); 
  return( 
    <Fragment>
     <ul>
       <h1>Text</h1>
         {this.products.map((item, index) => {
            return <h1 key={index}>{item.name}</h1>
         })
       }
    </ul>
   </Fragment>
  );}}
```

Me aparecen por consola, 2 arrays, uno vacío y el otro con la información, supongo que no me aparecen los nombres de los productos porque esta leyendo el primer array vacío.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 1):

No estas utilizando el estado del componente correctamente, para poder manejar variables debes crear un estado del componente, tambien estas ejecutando la consulta de los productos en el render del componente y te haria un bucle infinito

```
class Home extends Component{

// esto crea el estado del componente
state={
  products : []
}

constructor(){
    super();
    //this.products = [];
    this.obtenerProductos = this.obtenerProductos.bind(this);
}

componentDidMount(){
  this.obtenerProductos()
}

obtenerProductos(){
    const referencia = firebase.database().ref().child('products').orderByKey();
    let products = []
    referencia.once('value', snap => {
    snap.forEach(child => {

        var productElement = {
            id:          child.key, 
            name:        child.val().name, 
            price:       child.val().price,
            image:       child.val().image,
            category:    child.val().category,
            description: child.val().description
        };

        //this.products.push(productElement);
        products.push(productElement);
       });
    });
    this.setState({
      products
    })
}

render(){ 
  return( 
    <Fragment>
     <ul>
         {this.state.products.map((item, index) => {
            return <li key={index}><h1>{item.name}</h1></li>
         )}}
    </ul>
   </Fragment>
  );}}
```

Comment: Sigue sin almacenarme los valores, no debo colocar el state dentro del constructor? De esta manera: this.state={product: []} ?

Comment: Supongo que puede ser algun error con el codigo que recorre la información de la consulta del firebase, yo di por hecho que esa parte funcionaba, ya que no me ha tocado trabajarlo con firebase, podrias verificar si la parte de firebase esta funcionando? metiendo algunos console.log o algo de eso

Comment: Si lo de firebase esta funcionando. Coloque despues del render() un console.log(this.state.products) y efectivamente esta guardada la informacion, pero me aparecen dos arrays en chrome, uno vacio y otro con la informacion

Comment: puedes pegar aqui el resultado del console.log

Comment: Ya subí una foto de la consola

Comment: ok modifique la respuesta, el array vacio es el estado inicial, y el segundo array es cuando ya trajo los resultados, creo que lo que falta es meter el texto en un <li>

Comment: Ya coloque el <li>, y nada aún. Siento que es algo simple pero no lo veo

Comment: podrías abrir el inspector y ver si en el html de la pagina ya esta renderizado pero no se viera por alguna razón

Comment: Ya lo abrí, verifiqué y nada. Pienso que el problema es que esta mostrando el arreglo vacio del state inicial

Comment: Eso no tendría sentido ya que react se encarga de actualizar el componente cuando el estado cambia de forma automática, que no lo haga no seria común

Comment: No veo la solución

Comment: Si ves dos arrays, uno vacío y otro lleno es porque al principio cuando se renderiza el componente, en el estado no hay productos, despues de ejecutarse la funcion obtener productos, se modifica el estado y se vuelve a renderizar, por eso luego ves otro array con datos. Cerciorate bien de que en la funcion `render`, estas leyendo de `this.state.products` y no de `this.products` son dos cosas distintas

Answer (score 1):

El problema que te ocurre se debe a que la función obtenerProductos() utiliza una llamada asíncrona a la base de datos de Firebase para obtener los datos de los productos.

Cuando llamas a esta función dentro de la función render(), los datos aún no han sido obtenidos y la matriz products aún está vacía.

En lugar de llamar a obtenerProductos() en el método render(), debes llamarlo en el método componentDidMount() que se ejecuta después de que el componente se monta en el DOM. De esta manera, la matriz products tendrá los datos cuando se renderice el componente.

Aquí te cambio el codigo para solucionar el problema:

```
class Home extends Component {

  constructor(props){
      super(props);
      this.state = {
        products: []
      };
  }

  componentDidMount(){
      this.obtenerProductos(); 
  }

  obtenerProductos(){
      const referencia = firebase.database().ref().child('products').orderByKey();
      referencia.once('value', snap => {
          const products = [];
          snap.forEach(child => {

              var productElement = {
                  id:          child.key, 
                  name:        child.val().name, 
                  price:       child.val().price,
                  image:       child.val().image,
                  category:    child.val().category,
                  description: child.val().description
              };

              products.push(productElement);
          });
          this.setState({products: products});
      });
  }

  render(){ 
      return( 
          <Fragment>
              <ul>
                  <h1>Text</h1>
                  {this.state.products.map((item, index) => {
                      return <h1 key={index}>{item.name}</h1>
                  })}
              </ul>
          </Fragment>
      );
  }
}
```

De todas formas tambien te digo, que ya no se usan componentes en react y será por algo (por que es hay que escribir 200mil lineas de codigo innecesarias XD). Es mejor usar funciones y hooks.

En este case quedaría el codigo mas bonito, tal que así:

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react';
import firebase from 'firebase/app';
import 'firebase/database';

function Home() {
  const [products, setProducts] = useState([]);

  useEffect(() => {
    const referencia = firebase.database().ref().child('products').orderByKey();
    referencia.once('value', snap => {
      const productsArray = [];
      snap.forEach(child => {
        const productElement = {
          id:          child.key, 
          name:        child.val().name, 
          price:       child.val().price,
          image:       child.val().image,
          category:    child.val().category,
          description: child.val().description
        };
        productsArray.push(productElement);
      });
      setProducts(productsArray);
    });
  }, []);

  return (
    <ul>
      <h1>Text</h1>
      {products.map((item, index) => {
        return <h1 key={index}>{item.name}</h1>
      })}
    </ul>
  );
}

export default Home;
```